# How to get the value of the validated input when using @Pattern?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation, spring-el

I am using `@Pattern` to validate that the input matches an IP address:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$",message = "Invalid IP Address! {validation.value}")
```

Is there a way to tell spring to get the actual value in the message?

Right now I am getting:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: controllerMethod.ip: Invalid IP Address! {validation.value}
```

But I want

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: controllerMethod.ip: Invalid IP Address! BlaBlaBla
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Pattern(regexp = "...", message = "Invalid IP Address! ${validatedValue}")
```

I was having doubts about the ability of Spring to parse expression of SpEL within default validation messages.

While debugging, I managed to find out that the evaluation context is aware of a lot of properties including `regexp`, `payload`, `flags`, `groups`, `validatedValue`, and `message` (specifically for `@Pattern`).

You may include any of these to the `@Pattern#message` by surrounding the name with `${...}`.

Since Spring uses Hibernate Validator as the default reference implementation of JSR-303/JSR-349, it's worth reading Hibernate documentation: [Chapter 4. Interpolating constraint error messages](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator-backup/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-message-interpolation.html).